# Notification before keyboard hides?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, keyboard

I am trying to get a notification for just before the keyboard hides. I have tried the available notifications but they all seem to call just as the keyboard disappears of the screen. I need to run code just before the keyboard starts sliding down.

Answer (score 1):

Observe notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Method:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
}
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
}
```

It takes 0.25 or 0.3 to hide a keyboard.
If you need to do action before it will be hides, just make a timer for 0.2, you will have 0.1 before you finish your action.

Comment: Thanks Viktor but weirdly this doesn't work as expected which is why I asked. The `name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` only gets called as keyboard disappears off screen rather than just as its starts sliding down. Any clues?

Comment: It works for me. Looks like it call UIKeyboardDidHideNotification in your case.

Comment: Nope definitely calling the correct 'WillHide' notification. Why do you suggest a timer? I am currently just calling my code directly from the method you set as the selector.

Comment: I thought you need to do an action just before it hides. Because animation of hidings Keyboard takes 0.3 second.

Comment: But if I call the code directly in the method we create for the notification wouldn't it get called immediately before it moves down? Rather than just before it finishes.